# Is it possible to append the data from csv file to the existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a mysql table to which i have imported a csv file and if i try to import another csv file to the same mysql table will it replace the previous data or gets appended????

Comment: It gets appended.
it will not harm your existing records unless you have some sort of key defined in the table (like unique key... In that case you need to mention 'REPLACE' in your import query)

Comment: I'd say that depends on _how_ you import that CSV data. Why don't you simply try it with a test table?

Comment: import is like insert its not affect your previous data .it just appending

Comment: I have made id of the table as a primary key and it is auto incremented and when i import csv file the id will be auto incremented  right???

Comment: yes , You are right.
in your case data will be appended.
It wont do any harm to existing data, plus your id will be auto_incremented, no need to mention it in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV imports get treated as an INSERT statement which means no UPDATE is performed.